# Subset datatable by value corresponding to inner subset of other datatable

Tags: r, datatable, subset

I have an `objects` datatable that contains the `ID` and the length of the `Perimeter` of each of five objects. These objects share borders with each other. The `relations` datatable contains information on the length of the shared `Border` between each pair of objects, given as `ID.x` and `ID.y`. Here is the data:

```
objects <- data.table("ID" = c(5,4,3,2,1), "Perimeter" = c(500,400,300,200,100))
# The objects datatable:
#    ID Perimeter
# 1:  5       500
# 2:  4       400
# 3:  3       300
# 4:  2       200
# 5:  1       100

relations <- data.table("ID.x" = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5), 
                        "ID.y" = c(2,3,4,5,1,3,4,5,1,2,4,5,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,4), 
                        "Border" = c(20,40,60,80,20,70,10,60,40,70,150,20,60,10,150,90,80,60,20,90))
# The border length datatable:
#    ID.x ID.y Border
# 1:    1    2     20
# 2:    1    3     40
# 3:    1    4     60
# 4:    1    5     80
# 5:    2    1     20
# 6:    2    3     70
# 7:    2    4     10
# 8:    2    5     60
# 9:    3    1     40
#10:    3    2     70
#11:    3    4    150
#12:    3    5     20
#13:    4    1     60
#14:    4    2     10
#15:    4    3    150
#16:    4    5     90
#17:    5    1     80
#18:    5    2     60
#19:    5    3     20
#20:    5    4     90
```

Now, I want to subset the `objects` datatable using the outcomes from a corresponding subselection of the `relations` datatable. For example, I would like to select all objects of which the `Perimeter` minus the length of the `Border` with object with `ID == 4` is smaller than 180. In my example this should lead to the objects with `ID == 1` and `ID == 3` being selected, respectively because 100 - 60 = 40 < 180 and 300 - 150 = 150 < 180. I thought of achieving this as follows:

```
objects[ID!=4][Perimeter - relations[ID.x==4 & ID.y==ID]$Border < 180]
```

This yields the following error message:

```
Error: RHS of == is length 4 which is not 1 or nrow (20). For robustness, no recycling is allowed (other than of length 1 RHS). Consider %in% instead.
```

When changing `ID.y == ID` to `ID.y %in% ID` as the error suggest, the `Border` values of the selected `ID.x` and `ID.y` pairs, however, do not correspond with their values in the `relations` datatable...

```
print(objects[ID!=4][, border_length_with_obj_4 := relations[ID.x==4 & ID.y%in%ID]$Border])
   ID Perimeter border_length_with_obj_4
1:  5       500                       60  # should be 90
2:  3       300                       10  # should be 150
3:  2       200                      150  # should be 10
4:  1       100                       90  # should be 60
```

... leading to a faulty selection of the objects in the outer `objects[]` subselection:

```
objects[ID!=4][Perimeter - relations[ID.x==4 & ID.y %in% ID]$Border <= 180]
   ID Perimeter
1:  2       200  # should be object 3 instead of 2
2:  1       100
```

The error from before suggests that `ID` is of length 4 meaning that the `ID`'s of the objects are simultaneously passed to `ID` in `ID.y==ID`. Changing to `%in%` does lead to values being passed individually within the `relations[]` subset, however not in correspondence with the values passed to `Perimeter` in the `objects[]` subset. Is there any way this can be achieved? I.e. the desired output is:

```
   ID Perimeter
1:  3       300
2:  1       100
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to use a merge as follows:

```
objects[relations, on=c(ID="ID.y")][ID.x==4 & Perimeter - Border < 180]
   ID Perimeter ID.x Border
1:  1       100    4     60
2:  3       300    4    150
```